# in VB 2010, how do i make one button handle multiple click events?

Tags: windows, events, button, click, blackjack

For example, I am making a blackjack app and cannot figure out how to make the  button to function properly. I have it able to draw your third card, but I do not know how to draw the fourth and fifth card. The way I have it set up is Card 3, 4 and 5 already have a value but they are not visible. when the  button is clicked card3 becomes visible, when it is clicked again card4 is suppose to become visible and the same thing goes for card5. This is how i have it set up so far:

Private Sub BtnDrawCard_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnDrawCard.Click

```
    If BtnDrawCard.Capture Then
        LblPlayerThirdCard.Visible = True
```

What code would follow if i wanted each button click to bring up the next card?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flag indicating witch card it's the last showed card and test it on you click method or you can change the handler for the click

AddHandler BtnDrawCard.Click, AddressOf Me.MyNewClickEvent